# Can't run App Engine locally with BigQuery

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

When I import BigQuery:

`from google.cloud import bigquery`

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/manuelgodoy/Projects/Klein/src/application/storage/bigquery_models.py", line 6, in <module>
    from google.cloud import bigquery
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    __version__ = get_distribution('google-cloud-bigquery').version
  File "/Users/manuelgodoy/Projects/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/setuptools-0.6c11/pkg_resources.py", line 311, in get_distribution
    if isinstance(dist,Requirement): dist = get_provider(dist)
  File "/Users/manuelgodoy/Projects/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/setuptools-0.6c11/pkg_resources.py", line 197, in get_provider
    return working_set.find(moduleOrReq) or require(str(moduleOrReq))[0]
  File "/Users/manuelgodoy/Projects/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/setuptools-0.6c11/pkg_resources.py", line 666, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/Users/manuelgodoy/Projects/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/setuptools-0.6c11/pkg_resources.py", line 565, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)  # XXX put more info here
DistributionNotFound: google-cloud-bigquery
```

Does any one know how to solve this problem?

I installed the library exactly as Google documentation suggests:

`pip install --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery`

Comment: Are you using Standard env? And are you using some virtual environment (virtualenv, conda, pyenv)? Did you vendored the lib folder bigquery is installed to GAE?